# Type Cast Android cannot Cast 'Android .view.View to GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I am working on `GridView` in android Studio.
When I initialise the `GridView`, I am getting a type cast error:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.view.View' to 'com.example.pageviewer.GridView'

Can you any one please. Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: check your xml file or add xml file

Comment: whats your gridview reference? (e.g. import android.widget.GridView)

Comment: Just rename your classname. You shoudn't extend GridView from AppCompatActivity

Comment: Thanks every one :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Rename your GridView class to GridViewActivity and the problem will be solved.